# Should we install SP2013 on Server 2012 R2

Tags: 2013, installation, windows-server, infrastructure, sql-server-2012

This is a doublon of [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/91217/17814).

But since this post was answered, windows server 2012 R2 was released, and SP2013 SP1 (re)release.

We are about to set up a new SP environment for intra/extra net.

And wondering if it's the best way to choose 2012 R2 for our WebApplication Servers, and also for our SQL Server.
SQL 2012 server on a 2012 r2 is a good idea ? Or is it too risky. Same for SP2013.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. You convince me to go through 2012 R2. I feel sorry for you @fmeci, with Quest software. For now, we won't need to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the release of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1 (SP1), Microsoft did not support the installation of SharePoint Server 2013 in a Windows Server 2012 R2-based environment. However, with the release of SharePoint Server 2013 SP1, this configuration is supported in Windows Server 2012 R2.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274/en-us

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 supports Windows Server 2012 R2. I see no reason why you shouldn't run your SharePoint Server on a 2012 R2 Server. Just make sure you install SP1 correct before adding logic, solutions and content to your farm.

> Currently, Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 is not supported for installation on computers running the Windows Server 2012 R2 operating system.   Installing SharePoint Server 2013 on a computer that is running Windows Server 2012 R2 could lead to unexpected behavior, therefore, Microsoft does not support SharePoint Server 2013 in Windows Server 2012 R2.
>
> SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 and SharePoint Foundation 2013 with Service Pack 1 will offer support for Windows Server 2012 R2. The release date for Service Pack 1 for SharePoint Server 2013 and SharePoint Foundation 2013 is to be determined. This article will be updated as more information becomes available.

[SharePoint 2013 Support for Windows Server 2012 R2](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/09/22/sharepoint-2013-support-for-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well as you say, SharePoint 2013 SP1 is released now with support for Windows Server 2012 R2. So if you want to leverage some new feature in 2012 R2 there should be no problem using it for both SQL and SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using windows server 2012 R2 and sp2013 fundamentals SP1 currently. As far as I can say everything is working very good with SP 2013 SP1 in Windows server 201 r2. It is not very fast since I am using a virtual machine in my pc, but as a virtual machine its performance is very satisfactory. The only drawback is that I am having problems with Quest software Lotus migrator for sharepoint. I always get an error in snap-in. I have worked on this for 3 days now and there is no solution to error "B2A99A7809719294824D564B18CB8E4A9476E523". 
If you will be using it for sharepoint only, I would recommend this combination.